# Reference DBT variable in Jinja

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I have a project variable in the dbt_project.yml file called 'my_ids'.

```
vars: 
  my_ids: [1,2,3]
```

I am attempting to reference this variable using jinja in the models sql file.

```
    {% for id in my_ids %}
      SELECT * FROM table1 Where table_id_col = {{id}}
      
      {% if not loop.last %}
         UNION ALL
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to reference a variable within a jinja {%%} block ??

Many Thanks in advance.

M.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the project variable in model use the {{ var('...') }}. Below in your case

```
{% for id in var('my_ids') %}
      SELECT * FROM table1 Where table_id_col = {{id}}
      
      {% if not loop.last %}
         UNION ALL
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```